# Next button returns current record

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement a `Next` button in my view to go to the next record.

When I click the button, it just keeps calling the `Details` action in my controller for the current item rather than the next.

So if I am looking at `Sample` 1 and click `Next`, I can see that `sampleNumber` is still `1` when calling `Details` in `SampleController`.

Here is the code for the button in `Details.cs.html`:

```
@{
    if (Model.Pallet.Samples.Count > Model.SampleNo)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Sample"))
        {
            @Html.Hidden("sampleNumber", Model.SampleNo + 1)
            <input type="submit" value="Next" class="pull-right" />
        }
    }
}
```

And the `Details` method has the signature:

```
public ActionResult Details(int sampleNumber)
```

Any advice is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a new variable with

```
@{
   var next_record = Model.SampleNo + 1;
}
```

and change

```
@Html.Hidden("sampleNumber", Model.SampleNo + 1)
```

to

```
@Html.Hidden("sampleNumber", @next_record)
```

Answer (score 1):

By all appearances you're posting to the action `Details` however I'm not sure how you're passing the value to it.

So I see 2 parts to the solution.

1) You should just pass the view model to the controller action.

This has the advantage of being able to get the values, and increment the counter at the same time, removing that logic from the view.

Below, ViewModel will be the same type that is used for the `@model` part of the view.

```
public ActionResult Details(ViewModel vm)
{
    // Other logic to get details
    vm.SampleNo++;
    return View(vm);
}
```

2) Your hidden field for `sampleNumber` is not bound to the View Model, so when you do your post, the value that is passed is `Model.SampleNo` not `Model.SampleNo + 1` as I suspect you expect it to be.

You should change the `@Html.Hidden...` to `@Html.HiddenFor(Model.SampleNumber)` for the correct binding.

Comment: I am trying out option 1 but getting `The type or namespace name 'ViewModel' could not be found` for some reason ..

Comment: Updated. `ViewModel` is just a placeholder. It should be the same type as used for the `@model` part of your view.